# Is there a way to Assert that a code block doesn't compile?

Tags: c#, mstest, assert

In MS Test, is there a way to assert that a code block doesn't compile?  Let's say I have an object that I want to be a singleton.  I probably want to ensure that this object has no public constructors.  Is there a way to do something like this?

```
Action create = { new Logger("abc.txt") };
Assert.CompilerError(create);
```

I can do this using Reflection, but I was curious if there's a way to assert code doesn't actually compile.  Here's how I would do this using Reflection:

```
[TestMethod]
public void OnlyPrivateConstructors()
{
    var flags = (System.Reflection.BindingFlags)int.MaxValue; //all flags
    var constructors = typeof(Logger).GetConstructors(flags);

    foreach (var item in constructors)
    {
        Assert.IsTrue(item.IsPrivate);
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for hardcore Unit Testing.

Comment: No, there is not. Maybe you should instead think about creating a singleton. Having a singleton is the antithesis to unit testing.

Comment: I'm stepping through a TDD tutorial here http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/dommym/a-test-driven-development-tutorial-in-C-Sharp-4-0/ and it uses a singleton.  It asserts that two instances of Cannon refer to the same object, but I thought that that test would be defeated if the developer unintentionally had a public Cannon constructor.  In my post, I used a Logger class because I thought that a Logger class is the archetype of a singleton.

Comment: @user2023861 you are correct.  In the example, making the default Cannon constructor private forces a rewrite of the test.  There doesn't seem to be a test that would fail if someone later changes the constructor back to public.  If I were you, I would use the reflection approach you outline in your question.

Comment: @user2023861 I would `Assert.IsTrue(item.IsPrivate)`, however, since protected or internal constructors would also allow violations of the singleton pattern.

Comment: @phoog good point, see my edit.

Comment: @user2023861 Your test case name is backwards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MS test runs compiled code.  If the code doesn't compile, it can't be tested.

You could presumably do this with Roslyn by creating a string with the code block in question and then asking Roslyn to compile it.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/roslyn.aspx

Pre-roslyn, you could create a file containing your code block and then run csc against it using System.Diagnostics.Process or the like, but that's way more trouble than it's worth.

I would stick with reflection, but since internal or protected constructors would also permit violations of the singleton pattern, I would `Assert.IsTrue(item.IsPrivate)`.

I would also have a test for `Assert.IsTrue(typeof(Logger).IsSealed)`.  A bit of belt-and-suspenders, I suppose, but there iti s.

Comment: Pre-Roslyn there is the CSharpCodeProvider as I explained in my answer, but I do agree that it is probably more trouble than it is worth.

Comment: @JohnKoerner thanks for pointing that out, and +1 to your answer.  I had some vague thoughts about the CSharpCodeProvider but didn't pursue them because (again) it seemed to be more trouble than it was worth.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the CSharpCodeProvider to try and compile the code on the fly, but as Phoog says, its probably more trouble than it is worth:

```
        var compiler = new CSharpCodeProvider();

        string source = "using DLLBeingTested; \r\n" +
                        "public class DoIt {\r\n" +
                        "public void DoSomething() {\r\n" +
                        "var x =  new Logger(\"abc.txt\");\r\n" +
                        "}}" +
                        "";

        var loc = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);


        var cp = new CompilerParameters(new[] { Path.Combine(loc, "DLLBeingTested.dll") });
        cp.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.dll");
        cp.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Windows.Forms.dll");

        var assm = compiler.CompileAssemblyFromSource(cp, source);

        bool foundExpectedError = false;
        foreach (var err in assm.Errors)
        {
            if (err.ToString().Contains("CS0143"))
            {
                foundExpectedError = true;
            }
        }

        Assert.IsTrue(foundExpectedError);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're making the reflection code too complex. This gets you the same result with much less work, but as `phoog` mentioned, *you can't compile code that won't compile*.

```
[TestMethod]
public void NoPrivateConstructors()
{
    Assert.IsFalse(typeof(Logger).GetConstructors(/* binding flags... */).Any());
}
```

Comment: Depending on the binding flags, GetConstructors will also return private constructors.  I am not aware of a way to get it to return only non-private constructors.